# Why am I unable to equip the Drakefire Pistols?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

I just received a pair of the Drakefire Pistols, but they are obscured by a red cancel icon and I can't equip them. I'm sure that the dwarf was able to equip them in the first Vermintide, and I don't see anything telling me why I can't equip them now except for the red text on the item name and Ironbreaker.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ironbreaker" is the key here.

Bardin has 4 careers:

- Ranger Veteran (the default)
- Ironbreaker (accessible starting at level 7)
- Slayer (accessible starting at level 12)
- [Outcast Engineer](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1443780/Warhammer_Vermintide_2__Outcast_Engineer_Career/) (premium DLC career)

This particular weapon can only be equipped by the Ironbreaker and the Outcast Engineer careers.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't messed with any classes yet, just done a few quick matches.